# How to appreciate someone who is showing interest towards me?

Tags: etiquette

I like a person on linkedin. He is a information security veteran and very knowledgable and famous person. When I reach out to him, he was very eager and generous towards me. I wish I could say him that he is cool.

Question: In above case how can I appropriately appreciate someone with whom I have a professional relationship?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a phrasing request which is unfortunately not on topic here as per the [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Isn’t it fall under etiquette?

Comment: Per the help center I linked: "*Other types of questions that are off topic include questions that: **ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say**...*" (emphasis mine). If this were a physical interaction and you were asking us how to show you appreciate and admire a professional in your field, it may be on topic, but asking how to word a message is probably off-topic.

Comment: Okay, I am editing it

Comment: Currently this is voted as 'off-topic'. I think a better classification would be 'unclear what you're asking'. Appreciate this person how exactly? Are "thank you for your time" and "your help is really appreciated" not adequate?

Comment: Sorry to drop the last closevote, as worded your question was too-broad in my opinion. There's a whole lot of ways to say that you appreciate someone's work, or professionalism, or creativity, or... If you could narrow it down to be a little more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and why, your question could probably be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be sincere.  In other words, mean what you say.

Secondly, use your own voice.  Don't mimic others.

Thirdly, make it about him and not you.  Don't spend too much time talking about yourself if you're thanking him.  Focus on him, what he did, etc.

Finally be brief.  If he's famous he gets tons of message and won't want to read paragraphs and paragraphs.

For example:

> I think you're pretty cool for taking the time to help a newbie like me.  I hope I can be half as awesome as you one day. You're an inspiration to many - thank you!